# From post man(rest service) how to send json date(string format) to java which accepts date object

Tags: java, json, rest, java.util.date

How to bind dateOfJoining value(String type) to member variable "dateOfJoining"(Date type) in "DateInput" Class after sending below JSON through postman. How to convert String to Date object in java with the same format dd/MM/yyyy. Converted date should be in Date object but not String.

Json is as given below

```
{
 "dateOfJoining" : "03/04/2017"
}
```

Service URL hitting in postman -- localhost/Rest/hello

RestService class in java - HandleRestRequest.java

```
@RestController
public class HandleRestRequest
{

  @RequestMapping("\hello");
  public List setRequestParams(@RequestBody DateInput dateInput)
 {
   .......
  }
 }

 Pojo Class DateInput.java

  public class DateInput
 {
  private  Date dateOfJoining;
   .......
  }
```

If I send date from json in below format, its throwing error as unsatisfied input

```
 {
  "dateOfJoining" : 04/04/2017
 }
```

So I sending it as string format and by changing dateOfJoining as string in DateInput.java file and later I tried to convert it as date object as below

Modified DateInput.java file from Date to String

```
 public class DateInput
 {
  private  String dateOfJoining;
   .......
 }
```

Modified JSON

```
{
 "dateOfJoining" : "04/04/2017"
}
```

Code to convert user input from String to Date

```
 DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  String convertedDate = sdf.format(dateInput.getDateOfJoining());
```

Its converting into required format but return type is String but expected is Date object to send DAO layer. So I tried sdf.parse, its returning Date object but not in required format

```
Date date = sdf.parse(sdf.format(dateInput.getDateOfJoining()));
output is like -  Tue Apr 04 00:00:00 IST 2017
expected is 04/04/2017 (with return type Date object).
```

So please help me how to convert the string to date object with required format since DAO layer is expecting input as date object in format dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: Accept string as input and use Moment to convert to date

Answer (score 20):

Edit: Updating answer in accordance with updated question.

Use annotation `@JsonFormat` from [Jackson Databind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind) to specify the date pattern.

```
public class DateInput
 {
  @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
  private  Date dateOfJoining;
   .......
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I missed @RequestBody to keep in question. Now I updated question

Comment: But my project do not have Jackson Databind. What to do in that case?

Comment: Add the dependency. For using `@RestController`
, you must have been adding spring dependencies. Use the same way to add this one.

Comment: Working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

With JSON-B (included in Java EE 8) you can do this:

```
class DateInput {
    @JsonbDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
    public Date dateOfJoining;
}
```

In my tests with Thorntail 2.4 I don't need any annotation for ISO format when using `java.util.Date`:

```
{
    "dateOfJoining" : "2019-04-28T14:45:15"
}
```

Comment: Here we have same configuration, however it does not work. What dependency exactly do you have? io.thorntail/jsonb ?

Comment: `<groupId>io.thorntail</groupId><artifactId>jsonb</artifactId>`

Comment: and maybe something else? not from thorntail?

Comment: Just AMQ outside of Thorntail, from thorntail I have e.g. restclient and ejb.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to the below code snippet

```
public List setRequestParams(@RequestParam("dateOfJoining")@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")  DateInput dateInput)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you also explain how this new code answers the question?